# Datagridview to Excel: are you missing a cast?

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

Could you please let me know why I'm getting this error on worksheet = workbook.Sheets["Sheet1"]; & worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;

"Cannot implicity convert type 'object' to 'Microsoft.office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet = null;

            app.Visible = true;

            ***worksheet = workbook.Sheets["Sheet1"];***
            ***worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;***

            worksheet.Name = "Exported from gridview";
```

Comment: Did you even tried to search solution in web?

Comment: you don't have any Sheet1. Add the sheet first...